# Risk to Bitcoin balance when making Bitcoin Gold transactions

Tags: blockchain-fork, replay-attack, bitcoin-gold

If Bitcoin Gold fails to implement replay protection, will I risk losing my Bitcoin when I make a Bitcoin Gold transaction?

Assuming replay protection is not implemented properly, how can I protect myself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Bitcoin Gold implement replay protection?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/61220/how-does-bitcoin-gold-implement-replay-protection)

Comment: This question should be left open; the question suggested as a duplicate asks how replay protection is implemented whereas this one is asking about risk and risk-prevention.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article answering this very question https://bitcointechtalk.com/how-to-protect-against-replay-attacks-7a00bd2fe52f.

Through either careful transaction construction, using timelock supporting wallets, or simply waiting some time for things to be settled, you'll be safe.